# Options menu closes automatically on hardware button up (actionbarsherlock)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I am using actionbarsherlock where I listen to key up events and in case of hardware menu button, I force the menu to display like this

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
try {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            if (mMenu != null && mMenu.findItem(R.id.training_action_menu_group1) != null) {
                mMenu.performIdentifierAction(R.id.training_action_menu_group1, Menu.FLAG_PERFORM_NO_CLOSE);
            }

            return true;  
        }
    }
    return false;
} catch (Exception e) {
    ErrorUtil.handleSilentException(e);
    Log.e(TAG, "Error onKeyDown", e);
}
return false;
}
```

The problem is that the menu gets displayed when a user holds his finger on a hardware menu button, and when he moves the finger off - the menu closes. This happens for SGS 3 and other devices.
The flag `Menu.FLAG_PERFORM_NO_CLOSE` seems to be irrelevant to this issue, but it somehow fixed that issue for other android 2.3 phones.

How can I leave the menu open when the user moves his finger out of the button?

Comment: Why not leave the menu options menu handling to the system itself? Sure 2.2 and 2.3 menus may look a bit dated, but most users don't care.

Comment: I do not have any menu items hidden under overflow, so pressing hardware menu key without this code has absolutely no effect.
And this is not just about android 2.2 and 2.3. It's about all versions.